# Microsoft Dependency Injection resolving generic type returns null

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, dependency-injection

I am trying to translate something I used to do in Autofac to Microsoft Dependency Injection. I have a bunch of RequestHandlers that are based on an interface:

```
public interface IRequestHandler<TParameter, TResult>
    where TResult : IResponse
    where TParameter : IRequest
{
    TResult Handle(TParameter query);
}
```

I have registered all request handlers and all my IResponse objects and my IRequest objects by doing this:

```
 var request handlers = ReflectionUtils.GetClosedTypes(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), assemblies);
        foreach (var requestHandler in requestHandlers)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddScoped(requestHandler);
        }
```

Im collecting all my types to be registered like this:

```
 public static IEnumerable<Type> GetClosedTypes(Type openGeneric, params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        if (assemblies == null || assemblies.Length == 0)
        {
            return new Type[0];
        }

        var list = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
        {
            if (!assembly.IsDynamic)
            {
                var types = ReflectionUtils.GetExportedTypes(assembly);

                var q = from type in types
                        from i in type.GetInterfaces()
                        where i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGeneric
                        select type;

                list.AddRange(q);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

I can step through code and see that they are registered. I would then like to be able to retrieve them generically, by having a RequestDispatcher that retrieves the item from the ServideProvider and calls the Handle method:

```
 public TResult Dispatch<TParameter, TResult>(TParameter query)
        where TParameter : IRequest
        where TResult : IResponse
    {
        //Get the approproprite command handler by resolving it from the autofac _serviceProvider based on the IQuery and IQueryResult
        var handler = _serviceProvider.GetService<IRequestHandler<TParameter, TResult>>();
        return handler.Handle(query);
    }
```

But GetService returns null. I suspect it has something to do with the way items are registered in the container. Here is how I used to register things in Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(MyAssembly)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: You cpuld try inspecting the list of registered classes. Perhaps it is overwriting the registrations some how. E.g. registering them all as a `IRequestHandler`

Comment: Is `IRequestHandlerAsync` a derived type of `IRequestHandler`? Also, I do not believe that registering a concrete type will allow the DI container to automatically register its base types (or interfaces). Try to register the type by explicitly using the interface you want to resolve.

Comment: @Mardoxx I just fixed that. And Frederico it looks like the concrete classes are what is registered

Comment: Try registering like... idk, using a service descriptor then set it up using the type of interface as the resolving type and the concrete type as the thing that gets resolved?

Comment: I think what is happening here is you are registering the ConcreteType and expecting its implemented InterfaceType to resolve to it - which it doesn't do for you (i.e. registering Service which is Service : IService, and expecting IService to resolve to Service without explicitly telling it the relation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by changing the way you register your types into the DI container.

I believe that registering only the concrete type will not allow the service provider to resolve its interfaces (if not registered explicitly).

Try by providing the `ServiceCollection` all the types it needs:

```
public static IDictionary<Type, Type> GetClosedTypesRegistrations(Type openGeneric, params Assembly[] assemblies)
{
    if (assemblies == null || assemblies.Length == 0)
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    }

    return assemblies
        .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
        .SelectMany(ReflectionUtils.GetExportedTypes)
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetInterfaces(), (t, i) => new { service = i, type = t } )
        .Where(r => r.service.IsGenericType && r.service.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGeneric)
        .ToDictionary(r => r.service, r => r.type);
}
```

Inside `ConfigureServices`:

```
var requestHandlers = ReflectionUtils.GetClosedTypesRegistrations(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), assemblies);
foreach (var requestHandler in requestHandlers)
{
    serviceCollection.AddScoped(requestHandler.Key, requestHandler.Value);
}
```